# making a lowest value list in python from three other list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a large data set with 400 items_1 that are being compared with 400 other items_2, which is giving a score based on how each item compares to the other giving a weighted value_1. so I have three columns of about 160,000

input example
[input list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJq6H.png)

Item1
342
228
310
170
374
25
184
120
348
253
317
120
43
241
310
203

Item2
352
352
109
339
224
109
224
361
109
11
224
109
171
224
361
224

weight
1.815
2.024
2.045
2.062
2.087
2.104
2.127
2.128
2.138
2.146
2.148
2.15
2.177
2.18
2.181
2.183

each position on the list is corrilated to each other. so for the first set of values for item 1 and item 2 and wieght are all corrlilated values.

I am trying to build a list with this data set that fill filter all this data that will give me a range of item 1 with item 2 and with its weight the lowest values.
With item 1 ranging from 1 to 400 and item 2 ranging from 1 to 400 with out repeating values. but the weighted values need to be minimized.

output example

[output list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD0h7.png)

Item 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Item 2
32
2
10
5
1
8
3
15
45
18

weight
1.2
1.3
1.1
1.2
1.4
1.6
2.1
1.8
1.7
1.6

so I would be using the input list as a reference to look up values when I match item 1 with item 2 and find the lowest weighted values for each 400 comparision.

Any ideas how I can get started or were to begin. I would appreciate any help on this.

I tried using excel =INDEX(B2:B401,MATCH(MIN(C2:C401),C2:C401,0)) but this wont update based on my first column and sometimes gives me duplicate values. I was also think of using merge sort so I found some code that will sort one array, but I dont think thats what I want.

I am familiar with python, and bash either of those laungages I can use. I think I just need a little help in the right direction.

Comment: i don't quite understand, you yourself say these lists are already dependant. So is your question how to *sort* the weighted values while doing the same for your list items_1 and items_2 by size?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what your goal is, you can forge the 3 dependent lists together and sort them with an anonymous `lambda` function as key. For testing, i created 3 lists according to your example. For better understanding, the values of the same indices of `item_1` and `items_2` are calculated as sums and are written in `weights_1`, also at the same index, meaning *weights_1[x] = items_1[x] + items_2[x]*:

```
items_1 = [1, 4, 8, 3, 2]
items_2 = [4, 2, 1, 10, 11]
weights_1 = [5, 6, 9, 13, 13]
```

the following function takes these 3 lists, forges them together as a list of lists via a simple list comprehension, using each iteration-value and the current number of the iteration as indices for the other 2 lists and sorts them by the length of the "items_1" value at *index 0* `key=lambda x: x[0]`, you can change that, for whatever value you are trying to sort the lists.

```
def sort_lists(items1, items2, weights):
    combined_list = sorted([[items1[i], items2[i], weight] for i, weight in enumerate(weights)], key=lambda x: x[0])
    list_1 = [value[0] for value in combined_list]
    list_2 = [value[1] for value in combined_list]
    list_3 = [value[2] for value in combined_list]
    return list_1, list_2, list_3
```

to assign the results, you can just call the function somewhat like this:

```
items_1, items_2, weights_1 = sort_lists(items_1, items_2, weights_1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8] <- sorted values while still being coherent
[4, 11, 10, 2, 1]
[5, 13, 13, 6, 9]
```

you can do the same with the values of `items_2`, by just changing the `lambda x: x[0]` to `lambda x: x[1]`, i think you get the idea.

***Note that this definitely is not the best way to write this function, especially in terms of reausability. Its just an example to show you how it CAN be done!***